# Bluetooth gamepad misses input after idling for a few seconds

Tags: bluetooth, gamepad

OS: Ubuntu 23.04
GNOME: 44.0
Kernel: Linux 6.2.0-20-generic
(Basically stock ubuntu 23.04 desktop off ubuntu.com; installed <2 weeks ago)

As title.
My Xbox controller is paired via usb bluetooth adapter. After a few seconds of no input, the next input won't be registered. Interestingly, I've discovered I don't have this problem while the (gnome) bluetooth settings window is open. Also interestingly, I can tell see that something different is happening when that window is open by the indicator light on my bluetooth adapter. Based on that, it seems like its related to whether it's actively scanning for devices or not.
I suspect this is a power-saving feature, but I can't figure out how to turn it off. I've tried changing settings in `/etc/bluetooth` recommended in other questions (and restarting the bluetooth service), with no luck. I also tried using `bluetoothctl scan on`, but that seems to only scan intermittently.

If anyone knows how to fix this, I'd appreciate it.